# android studio recyclerview in multi-fragment tabbed activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am make a activity with 3 fragment, each fragment have recyclerview item.

I successfully make the first one fragment by a class RecyclerViewAdapter.

My question is, if i further make 2 another fragment with recyclerview item

should i make 2 more RecyclerViewAdapter new class, or just start another Viewholder in my first RecyclerViewAdapter class?

my RecyclerViewAdapter class here

```
public class TabMatch_RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TabMatch_RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

Context mContext;
List<Match> mData;
Dialog mydialog;

public TabMatch_RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Match> mData) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mData = mData;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v;
    v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.tab_match_item,parent,false);
    final MyViewHolder vHolder = new MyViewHolder(v);
    return vHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.tv_id.setText(mData.get(position).getId());
    holder.tv_weekday.setText(mData.get(position).getWeekday());
    holder.tv_date.setText(mData.get(position).getDate());
    holder.tv_time.setText(mData.get(position).getTime());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

public static class  MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView tv_id, tv_weekday, tv_date, tv_time, tv_league, tv_home, tv_away;
    private LinearLayout match_item;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        match_item = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_item_id);
        tv_id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_id);
        tv_weekday = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_weekday);
        tv_date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_date);
        tv_time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_time);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should i make 2 more RecyclerViewAdapter new class,

Practically, Each fragment must have its own `recyclerView` but `adapter` can be used to set on multiple `recyclerView`, Make sure you are creating new instance of adapter each time you set it to new `recyclerView`. This will be pretty handy, when it comes to managing stuffs in each `fragment`.